# How to convert such two datastruct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can i 
convert:

```
[{"year":2019, "title": "title0"}, {"year":2019, "title": "title1"},{"year":2018, "title": "title2"}, {"year":2018, "title": "title3"}]
```

to:

```
[{"year":2019, "list":["title0", "title1"]}, {"year":2018, "list":["title2", "title3"]}]
```

with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [{"year":2019, "title": "title0"}, {"year":2019, "title": "title1"},{"year":2018, "title": "title2"}, {"year":2018, "title": "title3"}];
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, {year, title}) => {
  a[year] = a[year] || {year, list: []};
  a[year].list.push(title);
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```